# build a new mysql variable from an existing date field

Tags: php, mysql, dateadd

I have a date column in my MySQL table and I want to build a new variable from that whereby I will add a few days.

example:

```
$date = 2014-12-12
```

now I need a second variable $date2 whereby the date will be 2014-12-17

So I need something like this

```
$date2 = $date + 5 days
```

I've searched for this and I got solutions for building queries, but I want to have a second variable. Is this possible?

I tried this (with no luck)

```
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date1);
$date2->modify('5 day');
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Could you post some more code?  I'm not sure what this has to do with MySQL.

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php - missing the `+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$date2 = strtotime($date) + (60*60*24*5); //convert date to unix time stamp and add 5 days
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', $date2); //convert back to readable format
```

Or an even better approach:

```
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . "+5 days"));
```

Comment: This works, thanks!
But the 'better approach' will not work. In that case $date2 is equal to $date1. I changed  "+5 days" into "+5 day" also, but still that doesn't work. I like the short approach better.

Comment: ah, got it. I have to use a . instead of a , So: 
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. "+5 days"));

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `+` in your `modify` call:

```
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date1);
$date2->modify('+5 day');
echo $date2->format('d-m-Y');
```